# How can I add "trim" to a curved surface?

Tags: mesh, objects

Very new to blender, so I am hoping this is an easy task that I just dont know the name of the function for.

I have a curved surface on an object that I am trying to add some raised trim around the edging (imagine a curved panel of armour on a knight).  To make the curved panel I uses a subsurface modifier.

I have tried selecting the faces towards the edge of he panel and extruding them along the normal but because of the curve of the plate the trim is not a uniform width in from the edge of the armour panel.

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this?

Edit:
Image added.

As you can see the trim on the armour panels is not uniform in width from the edge.  On the very curved panels when I use a loop cut they are not even, I was hoping there was a quicker way than having to adjust all the points by eye.
[image]

Comment: Can you add a small screenshot?

Comment: as said by others, share some image, of your current model and/or of a reference image that shows an example of what you wish to achieve

Comment: Added to he original message now.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Thanks Robin.  Sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame Blender doesn't directly have an 'Offset Even' tool, along  the perpendiculars to the edges being offset. A 2D curve can do it, so you could start with the trim, and build the plate away from it.. but starting with the plate as a mesh...

[image]

.. the <kbd>E</kbd> 'Even' option in the  <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> edge-slide tool means 'even along the crossing edge-rings', not a perpendicularly even distance from the loop itself. The illustration shows a sort of worst-case, with all the crossing edges vertical, so their density changes across the width. A simple  <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (above) doesn't work.

If you're building the trim **outwards** from the plate, you could:

1. Extrude the edges to be trimmed towards the center of curvature of the plate, like the rim of a *Solidify* modifier..
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> Extrude the new rim faces outward along their normals
3. Delete the surplus faces.

This method. though, builds the trim **inwards**.

1. As in 1. above, extrude the curve to be trimmed (top, in the picture below). This extrusion won't do anything except to tell the next operator what to do..

[image]

2. .. Which is <kbd>I</kbd> inset the region of all the faces in the original plate, with 'Even' checked, no 'Edge Rail', and no 'Boundary' inset. (Bottom, above).
3. The extruded faces have done their job, helping a selective inset, and can be deleted.

[image]

4. The new border-strip of faces can now be <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> extruded along its normals.

(I've had to tidy up the inside of the plate a bit, reconnecting the top and bottom with *Bridge Edge Loops* .. the topology inside your plate looks better than this, from what I can see)

Add a *Bevel* by angle modifier, and a *Subdivision Surface*..

[image]

The edge-lengths do check out.. they're pretty much the same all the way along the trim.

Comment: Thats so useful.  I need to read through this carefully (Im only just starting with Blender) to make sure what I need to do to get it right but I can see you've made the curve have a very even trim.